# How to change file associations on Mac OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, file-association

By default PNG images open in Preview. At some point, this has changed on my system so that clicking on a PNG file launches [Paintbrush](http://paintbrush.sourceforge.net/). While that's a really nice app, I'd still like the default to be Preview. How to change it back? (I formulated the question title to be little more generic — how to do this for any file types?)

I'm looking for the easiest, most readily-available way, with no 3rd party tools or going to the command-line. Somewhat surprisingly, System Preferences seems to contain nothing related to file associations.

This beginner question should probably be an easy one... I hope!

Comment: Additional question from Rajesh Vaghela (in an answer; reposting here as comment): "Any programmatic solution for this problem?"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

1. Get Info on the file in Finder (⌘I)
2. Find the "Open with:" section
3. Change the application to the one you want
4. Click "Change All…" to apply the change for all files of the same type.

[image: Info window]

Comment: Just wondering: during the 3 min 8 secs between me posting the question and you the answer, did you take the screenshot and upload it to imageshack yourself, or did you re-use someone else's pic? ツ

Comment: I took it myself, cleverly hiding my short username by collapsing the General section. `;)` I used the ImageShack uploader that I made myself (based on a widget): http://www.box.net/shared/06nnvqa5y5