# How do you read a .rdoc file on a Mac?

Tags: macos, mac, file-format

How do you read a .rdoc file on a Mac?

If I double-click it tells me there is no default application to read it.

Answer (score 2):

I found no references to "rdoc" extension except from Ruby [RDoc](http://rdoc.sf.net/) automated documentation generator. In this context these files are plain text files with some wiki-like markup. They can be opened in any text editor (or rename it to .txt if you want).

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, if it is a [Ruby Document](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_Document_format) file, I suppose you can just open it in a text editor (e.g. TextEdit).

Comment: If you find TextEdit (or some other app) suitable, you can set it as default easily: http://superuser.com/questions/29016/how-to-change-file-associations-on-mac-os-x